# Adding report to be printed together with sales order confirmation

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I've created a new Report summarizes the items in an order. This report works and is integrated into the order confirmation journal form (where you can print previously posted version of the confirmation) so that you can print it from there.

What I am struggling with is to have it printed automatically when the user generates a new confirmation (Proforma or otherwise). Luckily part of our customization is another report that is integrated exactly like I need mine to be. I've tried to copy as much as I could find from it but it is not enough.

What I've done so far:

- Added a new checkbox to the SalesEditLines form so I can check whether or not I want my report to be printed
- Modified the SalesFormLetter to:

  - add method to get/set a NoYes value on the contract
  - add methods to get and set PrinterSettings for the report on the contract
  - add method to open the PrinterSettings dialog for the report
- Modified the SalesFormLetterContract to add the NoYes and str fields for my report, integrated them into the pack/unpack macro and increased the current version macro
- Modified the SalesConfirmJournalPrint class with fields and get/set methods for my report

However none of this has been sufficient and I can't find anything else. Can someone explain to me what I'm missing or point me towards some resource that explains this FormLetter Framework? (All I've found is some useless MS document that waxes on lyrically about how much better it is in AX 2012 over 2009)

Comment: Have you checked the cross references of that other report? You should find some code that references one of the designs of the report, this should be the code that starts the printing.

Comment: @FH-Inway "yes", As much asI could. Unfortunately I don't have cross references for all methods since updating them takes ages and they invalidate so easily...

Comment: You can also try to set breakpoints in the code of the other report, then do a sales order confirmation and debug how that other report is called.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the updated FormLetter framework you asked for:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272871.aspx

What you're trying to do is a pain because everything is getting packed/unpacked, marshalled, etc. I think you might be missing `SalesFormLetterParmData` or `SalesFormletterParmDataConfirm`.

Your question isn't terribly clear with what is going wrong, so I might have misread it.